# Django django.contrib.gis.db MultiPolygonField extract points

Tags: django, geodjango

1. I didnt find any documentation about geo dgango that contains details about the fields. Only this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.MultiPolygonField but as you can see it is not telling us what is inside the fields and how to get it...
   Where can I find a deep view on the fields of geodjango such as MultiPolygonField ?
2. Im trying to extract all the points that are in MultiPolygonField. I tried:

   ```
   mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326, null=False, blank=False)

   def get_tooltip_title(self):
       result = "Polygon: [["
       for poly in self.mpoly.choices:
           for point in poly.coordinates:
               result += "("
               result += str(point.x)
               result += ","
               result += str(point.y)
               result += "),"
           result += "],"

       result += "]"
       return result
   ```

   But there is no "choises" in the field and I didnt found any good documentation about the field. So how can I get the points of a MultiPolygonField?

Comment: The only place that seems to have detailed information on this field (that I can find) is the source code https://github.com/django/django/blob/ecb59cc6579402b68ddfd4499bf30edacf5963be/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py#L383

Comment: so how developers suppose to use it? guess?!

Comment: You have unfortunately come across a part of the Django documentation that is not complete.  The source code may be the only answer here :(

Comment: But even the source code does not answer my question... I did not find how the MultiPolygonField is structured. Is it not open source then + no documentation?

Comment: You have to follow the inheritance backwards, e.g. MultiPolygonField inherits from GeometryField etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is so stupid. There is no good documentation?!

I found the solution in someones post from 2009 http://www.paolocorti.net/2009/04/01/a-day-with-geodjango/ . It is like:

```
class LocationPolygon(models.Model):
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326, null=False, blank=False)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def get_tooltip_title(self):
        return str(self.mpoly.coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though geodjango MultiPolygon isn't very well documented, mysql [multipolygon](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-multipolygon.html) is

> A MultiPolygon is a MultiSurface object composed of Polygon elements.
>
> MultiPolygon Examples
>
> On a region map, a MultiPolygon could represent a system of lakes.

The postgis [MultiPolygon](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Geography_Basics) is also very well documented with a few visual examples.

Basically a MultiPolygon is a collection of elements that may touch but not intersect.